# How to Integrate a Bing Map with an Offline WP7 App

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to develop a WP7 application that has a map in one portion of the display. Since it needs to be stand-alone, I need a utility that has built-in maps and does not need to surf the internet in order to operate. Is there any technique present there in wp7 to do the same. Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible, since Bing Maps doesn't work offline.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to use your own maps in the Bing Maps control, so you could include them in your application, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/mapcode.aspx).

Comment: yup certainly, but it had some copyright issues... we can't blindly go for the same

Comment: You can implement your own control then. It can't be too hard if you are already thinking of adding your own maps. Just handling some gestures to control zoom and offset and load and display map tiles for specific zoom range...